# .htaccess url: rewrite missing css javascript and images file at local host Xampp

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new on .htacees. I am trying to make user friendly URL for users using mode rewrite. My problem is that when i open **"user.php"** page using **.htaccess re:write** it can't load the **CSS file** or **images file** and show like this.

```
Sign up
My account
Hi
    My Profile
    My account
    Logout
    Help
    © 2014 Company, Inc.
```

I have a link like:

```
http://localhost/www.zeeshan.com/user.php?name=zeeshan06
```

New link is something like and its work 100% right for me.

```
http://localhost/www.zeeshan.com/user/zeeshan06
```

my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www.zeeshan.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)$ user.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

My CSS file path css/style.css , css/bootstrap.css, bootstrap.min.css in the www.zeeshan.com folder

```
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

with out .htaccess page work well and show css of div,panel etc. But using .htaccess 
re:write its cannot open **css file** and **images file**. please help me to solved my problem. Thanks..

Comment: please use full url for css and images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your paths for your CSS files are relative. So when you load up `http://localhost/www.zeeshan.com/user/zeeshan06`, your browser is looking for CSS files in a folder called `http://localhost/www.zeeshan.com/user/`. You need to change your paths to:

```
<head>
<link href="/www.zeeshan.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/www.zeeshan.com/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/www.zeeshan.com/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

Comment: +1 good answer. You can also use `<base href="/www.zeeshan.com/">` after `<head>` if you don't want to replace all your links

Answer (score 0):

If you put a static link on each page inside the `<base>` tag you'll need to change it all over again after deploy.

use this:

```
<base href= "<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/your_folder/" . "/>" ; ?>"
```

so you'll can upload to production and will never need change it again.